# How to compare an array with Hash records and retrive matching value? (from a Key/Value pair)

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

```
 foreach(@orphans1)
    {
        if(exists ($hash2{$_}))
        {
        my $values = values %hash2{$_};
        print "\n\n YES INSIDE THE LOOP: $values";
        }
    }
```

> Orphans is the array in which I am storing user names. I have to
>   compare Orphans records and find out matching keys from hash=>hash2 I
>   am able to compare and get keys which exists in hash2.
>
> But this code is not working when I try to retrieve corresponding
>   values.
>
> Sample data: Hash2 contains => {ASE, UK} {CCY, US} {PSD, US} {ZK9, UL}
>
> Orphans contains => ZK9, ASE

Comment: `values` returns you a list of values from the hash, which you're assigning to a scalar. That's almost certainly not doing what you had in mind - it'll give you simply a count of values in `%hash2{$_}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd write it:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @orphans1 = qw(ZK9 ASE);

my %hash2 = ('ASE' => 'UK', 'CCY' => 'US', 'PSD' => 'US', 'ZK9' => 'UL');

foreach(@orphans1){
print "In hash! key: $_ value: $hash2{$_}\n" if $hash2{$_};
}
```

---

```
In hash! key: ZK9 value: UL
In hash! key: ASE value: UK
```

Comment: I am not able to get the same output! Infact it did not find the matches inside hash.

Answer (score 0):

The next:

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @orp = qw(ZK9 ASE);
my %hash = ('ASE' => 'UK', 'CCY' => 'US', 'PSD' => 'US', 'ZK9' => 'UL');

my @o = @hash{@orp};  #values hash slice
say "@o";
```

prints

```
UL UK
```

Is that, what you want?

Or:

```
use 5.020;      #need 5.20
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @orp = qw(ZK9 ASE);
my %hash = ('ASE' => 'UK', 'CCY' => 'US', 'PSD' => 'US', 'ZK9' => 'UL');

my %h = %hash{@orp}; #key/value hash slice
say Dumper \%h;
```

prints

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ZK9' => 'UL',
          'ASE' => 'UK'
        };
```

Comment: $VAR1 = {
          'ZK9' => 'UL',
          'ASE' => 'UK'
        };

Comment: @SalyP check fugu's answer